# Etherscan sends back garbage values through API for the same query that works on the website

Tags: solidity, javascript, etherscan, alchemy

I'm trying to fetch data through the etherscan API from a proxy aave lending pool smart contract. This works absolutely fine for [AaveV1](https://github.com/aave/aave-protocol/blob/master/contracts/lendingpool/LendingPoolDataProvider.sol#L405) but for [AaveV2](https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/blob/master/contracts/protocol/lendingpool/LendingPool.sol#L590), it just sends back garbage values (uint min and uint256 max). I'm using the below code:

```
Aave Version 1 Smart contract
// Reading contract https://etherscan.io/address/0x398eC7346DcD622eDc5ae82352F02bE94C62d119#readProxyContract
// Works "ABI for the implementation contract at 0xc1ec30dfd855c287084bf6e14ae2fdd0246baf0d"
// Doesn't work "Previously recorded to be on 0xdb9217fad3c1463093fc2801dd0a22c930850a61"

const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const ethers = require("ethers");

async function main() {

    sampleAddressV2 = '0xd5c66bb825cf398d2b2035dcd8cdd102d9704f1c'
    sampleAddressV1 = '0x440efbba3f3d971fd8411c580197ecb53ef71f87'

    aaveLendingPoolV2Address = '0xc6845a5c768bf8d7681249f8927877efda425baf'
    aaveLendingPoolV1Address = '0xc1ec30dfd855c287084bf6e14ae2fdd0246baf0d'

    contractAddress = aaveLendingPoolV2Address
    sampleAddress = sampleAddressV2


    // creating a new Provider, and passing in our node URL
    const node = "wss://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/2z9JYK0TXfU2vWoNQgpjOltZ0amERORc"
    const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(node);
    //TODO: Remove API key
    apiKey = 'YourAlchemyAPIKey'


    // make an API call to the ABIs endpoint
    const response = await fetch('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address='+contractAddress+'&apikey='+apiKey);
    const data = await response.json();
    let abi = data.result;
    console.log(abi);


    //TODO: Remove private key
    let privatekey = "YourWalletPrivateKey";
    let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privatekey, provider);
    console.log("Using wallet address to sign txn: " + wallet.address);


    let contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, wallet);
    // console.log(contract)

    // getUserAccountData returns
    //       uint256 totalCollateralETH,
    //       uint256 totalDebtETH,
    //       uint256 availableBorrowsETH,
    //       uint256 currentLiquidationThreshold,
    //       uint256 ltv,
    //       uint256 healthFactor
    let read = await contract.getUserAccountData(sampleAddress);
    console.log("Value stored in contract is " + read.toString());
    // let read2 = await contract.resolvedAddress();
    // console.log("Value stored in contract is " + read2.toString());
}

const runMain = async () => {
    try {
        await main();
        process.exit(0);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

runMain();
```

When

```
    contractAddress = aaveLendingPoolV2Address
    sampleAddress = sampleAddressV2
```

I get

```
Value stored in contract is 0,0,0,0,0,115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
```

However, when

```
    contractAddress = aaveLendingPoolV1Address
    sampleAddress = sampleAddressV1
```

I get the correct values.

```
Value stored in contract is 48654124646394704110,48654124646394704110,27358021958082421204,1930253792696,4267156705104630589,70,65,1244895734848615672
```

The etherscan API works just fine from the website [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7d2768de32b0b80b7a3454c06bdac94a69ddc7a9#readProxyContract) as shown in attached screenshot[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the address `0xc6845a5c768bf8d7681249f8927877efda425baf` is the proxy bytecode contract. It doesn't store any data.

To make it work you have call `0x7d2768dE32b0b80b7a3454c06BdAc94A69DDc7A9` with the ABI at the `0xc6845a5c768bf8d7681249f8927877efda425baf`.

```
// For V2
contractAddress = aaveLendingPoolV2Address
proxyAddress = "0x7d2768dE32b0b80b7a3454c06BdAc94A69DDc7A9"

[..]

let contract = new ethers.Contract(proxyAddress, abi, wallet)
```